# Active admin default links only for certain users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, authlogic

In active admin, I want to only let certain users be able to download csv of table data.

I know how to shut it off for all users like this:

```
index :download_links => false do
  # columns
end
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
index :download_links => current_admin_user.can_download? ? [:csv] : false do
  # columns
end
```

But I don't have access to current_admin_user. ALso, I've tried setting parameters in a before filter, but that didn't work either. I'm stuck at the moment, and am trying to figure this out.

I'm using authlogic along with active admin with rails.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. It wasn't too bad, I just had to go about the problem differently. Just add this method to application_controller.rb

```
def require_can_download_for_csv
  raise unless current_admin_user.can_download?
end
```

And then add this to your active_admin initializer:

```
config.before_filter :require_can_download_for_csv
```

And that's it!